# Python - Count words in a given text

Tags: python, string, search, count

I'm new to coding so forgive me if I ask something that was already answered but believe me that I did search for answer and couldn't find it.

I have a task do count how many of given words are in given text. Word can be a hole or part of other word. Letter case does not matter. If word appears several times in the text, it should be counted only once.
So far I managed to come to this:

```
def count_words(text, words):
    count = 0
    text = text.lower()
    for w in words:
        if w in text:
            count =+ 1

    print (count)

count_words("How aresjfhdskfhskd you?", {"how", "are", "you", "hello"})
count_words("Bananas, give me bananas!!!", {"banana", "bananas"})
count_words("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
                       {"sum", "hamlet", "infinity", "anything"})
```

With that code I manage to get final count of 1 for all tree texts and of that only third is ok.

As I see it, my first problem is that my text.lower() doesn't do anything and I tough it should lower all cases.

My second problem is that in first case "are" isn't found in "aresjfhdskfhskd" but in third case "sum" is found in "ipsum". Both of that words are part od larger word but first isn't found and second is.
Also, in second case result should be 2 because there are banana and bananas, similar but different.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure yet about the second and third issues, but `text.lower()` doesn't modify the string. It _returns_ the string but in lowercase. Use `text = text.lower()`

Comment: The crucial mistake is `count = +1` versus `count += 1`.

Comment: Thank you both. That solved part of problem.

Comment: Besides the count mistake, change the for statement to `for w in words.lower()`.  Are your 'words' always lower case? Else you have to call `lower()` on them too.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and a generator expression, this seems the simplest solution:

```
text = text.lower()
count = sum(word in text for word in words)
# bools are cast to ints (0, 1) here
```

Comment: While correct (and solving the problem), this solution does not seem to really solve the issue, namely understanding what is wrong and learning. Type coercion tricks are not going to help there. Add.: if you're going minimal, you might as well do `text.lower()` in the expression as well.

Comment: @Joost You are right, of course. The real (banal) issues have already been posted and duly upvoted in the comments. Nevertheless, why not suggest a cleaner shorter easy-to-read and probably instructive alternative?

Comment: @Joost True, but then `lower()` would be called for every iteration.

Comment: I think that I've learned something that I din't knew before I've asked the question so I guess in the end it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 2):

First - strings are immutable, so `text.lower()` is not changing `text` itself, but returns new instance - lowercased. Other problem is that `if a in base` checks if exists, without info how many times...

```
def count_words(text, words):
    count = 0
    lower_text = text.lower()
    for w in words:
        print w + " - " + str(lower_text.count(w))

print "1"
count_words("How aresjfhdskfhskd you?", {"how", "are", "you", "hello"})
print "2"
count_words("Bananas, give me bananas!!!", {"banana", "bananas"})
print "3"
count_words("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
                   {"sum", "hamlet", "infinity", "anything"})
```

Comment: @DejanJovanovic No problem - Schwobaseggl's answer is more Pythonic, but I think you need to get ready for it. If you need good source of information - please follow this link http://www.diveintopython.net/ :)

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll sure follow it since I know how much I don't know. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is partially wrong. Try this:

```
def count_words(text, words):
    count = 0
    lower_text = text.lower()
    for w in words:
        if w in lower_text:
            count += 1

    print count

count_words("How aresjfhdskfhskd you?", {"how", "are", "you", "hello"})
count_words("Bananas, give me bananas!!!", {"banana", "bananas"})
count_words("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
                   {"sum", "hamlet", "infinity", "anything"})
```

This will only work in Python 2.7 though so if you're using Python 3+ you need to change the final `print` to `print(count)`.